# How remove escape characters

Tags: c#, regex, string

In the page script I have:

```
imgLocStr[0][0] = "gau"
imgLocStr[1][0] = "swo"
imgLocStr[2][0] = "gau"
imgLocStr[0][1] = "swo"
imgLocStr[1][1] = "swo"
imgLocStr[2][1] = "swo"
imgLocStr[0][2] = "swo"
imgLocStr[1][2] = "swo"
imgLocStr[2][2] = "swo"
```

But when Im parsing the html code I got"

```
"imgLocStr[0][0] = \"gau\"\n  "
```

How I remove the `\`  and and `\n` at the end only need the values `"gau"` or `"swo"`

I can use `IndexOf("\")` and `SubString()` but Im sure there is an easy way to do this.

Comment: Those escapes are, quite possibly, the result of *viewing the string in VS debug windows*. (In which case VS may show the string "as if it were typed in C#, as a literal"; the extra escapes don't *really* exist in the data.)

Comment: @user2864740 You are right when I debug the data I saw those escapes. But the point is I need extract the values and when using IndexOf you have to count those characters

Comment: `when using IndexOf you have to count those characters` No you don't, if they (like \\) aren't really there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Regex.Replace(originalString, @patern, string_to_sustitute)`which returns a new string with all the apperances of the pattern replaced with the string_to_sustitute

Answer (score 0):

Try Regex: `"\w+"` to get `"gau"` or `"sau"`.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/GE2zqO/1)

use [Regex.Match](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.match?view=netframework-4.7.2) in C#

Answer (score 0):

The backslashes `\"` are to escape the double quote in the string.

To remove the newline and the space at the end you might use `\s+$` to match 1+ times a whitespace character till the end of the string.

Fo example:

```
String str = "imgLocStr[0][0] = \"gau\"\n  ";
Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace(str, @"\s+$", "")); // imgLocStr[0][0] = "gau"
```

To get your value using a regex you might use an alternation and specify your allowed values:

`"(?:gau|swo)"\s*$`
<sup>[demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%22%28%3f%3agau%7cswo%29%22%5cs*%24&i=imgLocStr%5b0%5d%5b0%5d+%3d+%22gau%22+%0d%0a%0d%0aimgLocStr%5b1%5d%5b0%5d+%3d+%22swo%22%0d%0aimgLocStr%5b2%5d%5b0%5d+%3d+%22gau%22%0d%0a%0d%0aimgLocStr%5b0%5d%5b1%5d+%3d+%22swo%22%0d%0aimgLocStr%5b1%5d%5b1%5d+%3d+%22swo%22%0d%0aimgLocStr%5b2%5d%5b1%5d+%3d+%22swo%22%0d%0aimgLocStr%5b0%5d%5b2%5d+%3d+%22swo%22%0d%0aimgLocStr%5b1%5d%5b2%5d+%3d+%22swo%22%0d%0aimgLocStr%5b2%5d%5b2%5d+%3d+%22swo%22&o=m)</sup>

Or use a negated character class to match not a double quote or a newline:

`"[^"\r\n]+"\s*$`
<sup>[demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%22%5b%5e%22%5cr%5cn%5d%2b%22%5cs*%24&i=imgLocStr%5b0%5d%5b0%5d+%3d+%22gau%22+%0d%0a%0d%0aimgLocStr%5b1%5d%5b0%5d+%3d+%22swo%22%0d%0aimgLocStr%5b2%5d%5b0%5d+%3d+%22gau%22%0d%0a%0d%0aimgLocStr%5b0%5d%5b1%5d+%3d+%22swo%22%0d%0aimgLocStr%5b1%5d%5b1%5d+%3d+%22swo%22%0d%0aimgLocStr%5b2%5d%5b1%5d+%3d+%22swo%22%0d%0aimgLocStr%5b0%5d%5b2%5d+%3d+%22swo%22%0d%0aimgLocStr%5b1%5d%5b2%5d+%3d+%22swo%22%0d%0aimgLocStr%5b2%5d%5b2%5d+%3d+%22swo%22&o=m)</sup>

You could specify a more exact pattern using an anchor to assert the string of the string `^` and specify what you would allow between the opening and the closing quotes at the end of the string `$`:

`^imgLocStr\[\d+\]\[\d+\] = ("\w+")\s*$`
<sup>[demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5eimgLocStr%5c%5b%5cd%2b%5c%5d%5c%5b%5cd%2b%5c%5d+%3d+%28%22%5cw%2b%22%29%5cs*%24&i=imgLocStr%5b0%5d%5b0%5d+%3d+%22gau%22+%0d%0a%0d%0aimgLocStr%5b1%5d%5b0%5d+%3d+%22swo%22%0d%0aimgLocStr%5b2%5d%5b0%5d+%3d+%22gau%22%0d%0a%0d%0aimgLocStr%5b0%5d%5b1%5d+%3d+%22swo%22%0d%0aimgLocStr%5b1%5d%5b1%5d+%3d+%22swo%22%0d%0aimgLocStr%5b2%5d%5b1%5d+%3d+%22swo%22%0d%0aimgLocStr%5b0%5d%5b2%5d+%3d+%22swo%22%0d%0aimgLocStr%5b1%5d%5b2%5d+%3d+%22swo%22%0d%0aimgLocStr%5b2%5d%5b2%5d+%3d+%22swo%22&o=m)</sup>